# How to access class member attribute that's specified in a member function in python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm working on a python project using selenium and I need to access a member attribute who's value is specified in another member function, I can't seem to figure it out although i know it's an easy fix here's my code and what I've tried so far

```
`class User_data:
'''Get important info ab user'''
def __init__ (self, url, product_name):
    self.url = url
    self.product_name = product_name

def askFor_info (self):
    self.url = str(input("Please enter the url of the site you wish to make purchase from: "))
    self.prodcut_name = str(input("Please enter the name of the product you wish to purchase: "))

    # person = User_data(url = self.url, product_name= self.product_name)

    print(f"{self.url},", f"{self.prodcut_name}")
```

**this is the piece of code that's wrong**

> driver.get(User_data.askFor_info.url)

> when i do this i get an error that says " AttributeError: 'function'
> object has no attribute 'url'"

Answer (score 0):

`askFor_info` is a method and `self.url` is a class member so to access that variable, First you need to instantiate the class using

```
user_data = User_data("MY URL", "MY PRODUCT NAME")
# Then run the method askFor_info
user_data.askFor_info()
# Then you can fetch the url inputted by user by
user_data.url # Updated URL from USER INPUT
user_data.product_name # Updated Product Name from User Input
```